# Figuring out function composition

Tags: function-and-relation-composition

If I know $f(x)$ and $f(g(x))$,

how do I figure out what is $g(x)$?

I can solve already some simple cases, but I'm looking for a general strategy.

Particularly in harder cases when just trying to figure it out is hard.

Comment: Can you provide an example that might illustrate where you're getting stuck?

Comment: I was just wondering is there any way to find solution to $g(x)$. I mean any other than just trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Set $h$ so that $f(g(x))=h(x)$.

To get $g(x)$, $f$ is disturbing. $g$ is composited with $f$ from the left. You need the inverse operation. The inverse operation of composition from the left is the [left inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Left_and_right_inverses).

Let $f^{-1}$ denote the left inverse of $f$:

$$g(x)=f^{-1}(h(x))$$
$\ $

Let's presuppose that $f$ and $g$ are functions.

If $f$ is bijective, you can set the [inverse function (compositional inverse / inverse)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function) of $f$ for $f^{-1}$.

If $f$ is not bijective, you have to choose suitable [partial inverses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Partial_inverses) of $f$ for $f^{-1}$. The equation above can give you $g$ as a piecewise given function then.